# Buttons on mainsite look disabled

Tags: bug, design

Take a look at the following two screenshots. They are our close dialog and our flag dialog.

I have selected an option, and the button is enabled and I can click it to submit my close vote or my flag.

The button looks disabled though. It's greyed out. It looks like I haven't done something right, or like I can't actually close or flag this question.

It used to be orange or blue or something other than this.

[image: close dialog: greyed out close button]
[image: flag dialog: greyed out flag button]

This appears to occur in a number of places with buttons of this style, e.g.:

- [The search button](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search)
- [Post your question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)
- "Save your edits" on any post
- [Why do all buttons on this site appear to be disabled?](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2735/2698)

Comment: _All_ submit buttons are like this, including the ["Search"](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search), "Post Your Answer", ["Post Your Question"](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) and "Save Edits" ones, and those that only mods can see.

Comment: By upvoting this question, does it mean that "I agree with this bug" and so it should be left in?

Comment: Lol, I think it means "this is a useful bug report".

Comment: Might this have something to do with SE standardizing the themes?

Comment: I've noticed the same issue recently on the 'Save Edits' button - I figured maybe it was just bad for those of us with color blindness issues.

Comment: Note that this appears to be addressed (based on some quick tests) in the new site theme that is currently in [testing](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2744/game-development-updated-site-theme-is-ready-for-testing).

Comment: Confirmed. Looks much better in beta theme.

Comment: I'll tag this as completed once the beta theme leaves beta, then.